# Loading large images Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using ImageLoader in my app to load images for tableview. It works perfect for small images as it was designed for. But in my app I load some images that are nearly 3MB and when I load in a tableview(4-5 cells) my app crashes after couple of refreshes. I understand that the ImageLoader is not the right API for this, but how do I download or infact load a scaled down version of the image so that there is no memory hog. The tableview does not need a high resolution image and since its showing a small thumbnail size, I would like to know what is the best option to load in IOS and if there are any predefined API available?. (For Android I use the android developer recommended bitmap sizing functions to scale down the image).

Answer (score 0):

UIImage has a Scale() function.

```
UIImage imageToBeScaled ...
UIImage scaledImage = imageToBeScaled.Scale (new SizeF (newWidth, newHeight));
```